# Rails tutorial port to amazon dynamodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, railstutorial.org, amazon-dynamodb

I'm following michael hartl's tutorial for getting started with rails...

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

I'm trying to modify my database backend from PostgreSQL to Amazon dynamodb.. Any advice/help on how to achieve this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be tough because Hartl's tutorial stresses learning ActiveRecord knowledge very strongly, whose core components don't really make sense in the context of DynamoDB.

If you're insistent, Amazon provides the aws-sdk gem that you can bundle into your application. Set up your appropriate credentials in the config/initializers/aws.rb initializer

```
AWS.config({
  :access_key_id => 'your_access_key_id',
  :secret_access_key => 'your_secret_access_key',
})
```

You'll probably want your models (where appropriate) to inherit from AWS::Record::HashModel if you want to have a sensible way of interfacing with objects.

You'll also probably want to write some assessors in this format.

```
  def img= image
    self.has_image = true 
    AWS::S3.new.buckets[:images_cloudstock].objects[id].write(image.read)
  end

  def img
    AWS::S3.new.buckets[:images_cloudstock].objects[id].url_for(:read) if has_image
  end
```

Comment: could you outline which models should inherit from AWS::Record::HashModel? that would be most helpful! And where will I need to change the accessors? Sorry about the noob questions but I'm just beginning to learn RoR. will the twitter clone example still work after I make these modifications?